# What is this electrical component circled in blue in this engine bay?

Tags: electrical, part-identification, electronics

[image]

I was wondering what this component could be. i couldnt post full size picture since it was over 2mb but full picture also showed a part that looked similar to the part circled in blue. i think that other part was the voltage regulator for the generator but i dont know what that thing circled in blue is

Comment: Looks similar to a late 60's early 70's horn relay. Put your hand on  it and have someone honk the horn. If it is a horn relay you should feel it vibrate or click when the horn beeps.

Comment: What year & model of the Ford? It looks like an ignition control module, but would be better able to tell you with information about the vehicle. There's too many wires coming out of it to be a horn relay.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2♦ 1968-1972 Ford Taunus P7B 20m with the Köln V6 engine. There are diagrams in this site https://www.fordopedia.org/parts-catalog/early-v4-v6 , also in this link: "https://www.fordopedia.org/parts-catalog/early-v4-v6/TV7.60"  the part with the number 7 kind of looks like the part that i circled in blue in the original post i made but it doesnt say what type of part it is, it just says part 7 and im not sure if its actually the same thing as i circled in the original post.

Comment: Take a look at TV7.61, part #2. I'm still leaning on this being the ignition control module for the ignition. While it doesn't look exactly the same, it seems right. The part you showed in TV7.60 is the ignition resistor which you can see straight behind the air cleaner assembly in your image. (It's the white thing with a metal strap and wires out either end.) On the part in question, if you can trace the wires back to where they connect to anything, it'd be a big help. If it connects back to the distributor and/or coil, I'm probably on the right track.

Comment: @NetServOps - I'm wondering how you came to that conclusion? How many wires does it take to serve a horn as a relay?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I would agree with you, it is similar looking to a horn relay but it is an ignition control module.
I've looked at pictures of empty engine bays with that exact part and the wires lead back to the firewall on the drivers side.
So, I'm sure you got this one.